# How to highlight certain word?

Tags: terminal, highlighting

How do I highlight certain word using the `cat` command on the terminal?

Answer (score -1):

Type `cat (the name of your textfile) | grep (The word you want to highlight)`, e.g `cat textfile | grep in`.

Comment: This would only work if grep is aliased with --color. In addition, it is not needed to cat and then grep, you can just `grep some_word textfile`

Comment: To be fair, the question requires the use of cat :)